# Are these quartz cron expressions correct?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I have two cron jobs, one runs at midnight from MON to SAT and one runs at 2am on SUN.  Are the below correct?

1) Execute at midnight from Mon to Sat

```
0 0 0 ? * MON-SAT *
```

1) Execute at 2am on Sunday

```
0 0 2 ? * SUN *
```

Are these correct cron expressions for what I need?

Ideally, I want to combine these two cron expressions into one.  Is that possible? If so, what is the new cron expression please?

Answer (score 0):

Your expressions are right, you can check them here:
[cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Unfortunately as I know you can't combine your two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CronExpression class with Quartz 2.2.1. (Sorry, I'm not sure since which Quartz version can be used it)

[CronExpression Java Doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/CronExpression.html#validateExpression(java.lang.String))

I believe the above one can be checked your expression properly.